# Get formated date in php using mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to get formated date in php from mysql database Like 21st March 2013 11:21AM

Comment: And in which format is your date stored in your MySQL database?

Comment: Pls visit this url.[link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: -1 for not reading the PHP manual first before asking and another -1 also for not reading the MySQL manual.

Comment: I really think that you could have typed this into Google and been done by the time you made an account and posted this

Comment: 7 answers for a question that did now show the slightest attempt to solve the issue.. edit: and two votes up

Comment: Can we close this question shall we?

Comment: @mishu "OMG I know one...hmm www.google.com date format mysql....ctrl c ctrl v. "

Comment: @blackhatshadow haw u dble downvote pls?

Comment: I don't. Actually I'm just trying to say that he/she must have another -1 for not reading MySQL manual :)

Comment: @JW, with all due respect sir, I don't have the right to do that. But you can, so why don't you?

Comment: Sorry sir, it's `3000` :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use MySQL's built-in function called `DATE_FORMAT()`

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%D %M %Y %h:%i%p')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/9407)
- [DATE_FORMAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

OUTPUT

```
╔═════════════════════════╗
║     FORMATTED_DATE      ║
╠═════════════════════════╣
║ 22nd March 2013 06:07AM ║
╚═════════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DATE_FORMAT` MySQL function.

**Example**

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'DATEFORMATE') // DATEFORMATE can be %b %d %Y %h:%i %p
```

**OR**

```
STR_TO_DATE('$date', 'DATEFORMATE')
```

**HOW TO USE IN QUERY**

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('YOUR DATE FIELD','DATEFORMAT') FROM table;

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'DATEFORMAT') FROM table;
```

***[`DATEFORMATE Options`](http://davidwalsh.name/format-date-mysql-date_format)***

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [MySQL's DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)?

For your example, add this to your MySQL query:

```
DATE_FORMAT(my_date, '%e %M %Y %h:%i %p')
```

Comment: this will be the output of your formatted date, `22 March 2013 06:10 AM`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DATE_FORMAT()`

```
SELECT * FROM table DATA_FORMAT(NOW(), '%D %M %Y %h:%i%p')
```

Tutorial on [DATE_FORMAT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp)

Answer (score 0):

What format is your database column in?  If it's a UNIX timestamp, just feed it into `date`.  If it's a date column (formatted as 'YYYY-MM-DD' or 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'), feed that into `strtotime`, then into `date`.

So, assuming it's a date column, you'd want to do something like this:

```
$column_value = "2013-03-01 00:00:00";    // Get this from your database however you like

$formatted_date = date("jS F Y H:i A", strtotime($column_value));
```

The documentation on how to use `date` for formatting is in [the PHP documentation.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$date   = date from databse // some thing like 2013-03-22 11:38:00

$dt     = new DateTime($date);
echo $dt->format('jS  F Y g:ia');
```

Output : `22nd March 2013 11:38am`

Ref : http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php